# How can Kafka Streams throughput be increased?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Currently ~70 records/s will be processed on a single node with a single Kafka broker.
The throughput is low, as is the CPU utilisation and the memory usage.
My topology:

```kotlin
projekte
    .leftJoin(wirtschaftseinheiten)
    .leftJoin(mietobjekte)
    .cogroup { _, current, previous: ProjektAggregat ->
        previous.copy(
            projekt = current.projekt,
            wirtschaftseinheit = current.wirtschaftseinheit,
            mietobjekt = current.mietobjekt,
            projektErstelltAm = current.projektErstelltAm
        )
    }
    .cogroup(projektstatus.groupByKey()) { _, projektstatusEvent, aggregat -> aggregat + projektstatusEvent }
    .cogroup(befunde.groupByKey()) { _, befundAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + befundAggregat }
    .cogroup(aufgaben.groupByKey()) { _, aufgabeAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + aufgabeAggregat }
    .cogroup(durchfuehrungen.groupByKey()) { _, durchfuehrungAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + durchfuehrungAggregat }
    .cogroup(gruppen.groupByKey()) { _, gruppeAggregat, aggregat -> aggregat + gruppeAggregat }
    .aggregate({ ProjektAggregat() }, Materialized.`as`(projektStoreSupplier))
```

I've tried to increase different size to feed more data to my stream:

- cache.max.bytes.buffering: 52428800
- max.request.size: 52428800
  but they didn't measurably help.

How can I increase throughput to achieve optimal system utilisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following properties I could speed up processing by factor 4 by increasing I/O throughput:

```yaml
# consumer
max.partition.fetch.bytes: 52428800
max.poll.records: 5000
fetch.min.bytes: 5242880
#producer
max.request.size: 52428800
batch.size: 200000
linger.ms: 100
# common
cache.max.bytes.buffering: 52428800
```

Increasing parallelism to 20 on a 24-core system I further could achieve an optimal CPU utilisation of 80% and speed up the processing further by a factor of 9:

```yaml
num.stream.threads: 20
```